# How do you merge and close a pull request that has a conflict?

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request

Say I merge in one pull request, which then makes another one out of date and unable to be merged in.

I then do the following:

```
$ git remote add <username> <URL>
$ git fetch <username>
$ git co -b <pull-request-branch> <username>/<pull-request-branch>
$ git rebase master
```

*Make the appropriate changes*

```
$ git add .
$ git rebase --continue
$ git checkout master
$ git merge <pull-request-branch>
$ git push origin master
```

But this does not automatically close the pull request.

Is there a way to directly `fetch` the pull request itself, merge it in, and then push back to master to automatically close the pull request?

Answer (score 0):

As documented, a [PR is closed when merged into the `master` branch](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request/).

Except here, you changed completely the PR branch, by rebasing it on top of master.
That is not your role. The contributor submitting a PR is supposed to do that (rebasing on top of `upstream/master`, with `upstream` being a remote referring to your original repo)

You should only merge the PR branch, and the merge should be a fast-forward one.

> Is there a way to directly fetch the pull request itself, merge it in, and then push back to `master`?

That is what you started to do:

```
git remote add <username> <URL>
git fetch <username>
```

Then:

```
git checkout master
git merge <username>/<pull-request-branch>
git push
```